# The Kuratowski Monoid

Tags: general-topology

I have been reading the paper "[The Kuratowski closure complement theorem](http://nzjm.math.auckland.ac.nz/images/6/63/The_Kuratowski_Closure-Complement_Theorem.pdf)" by "B. J. Gardener and M. Jackson". In that the author discusses the 6 different monoid structures as follows: Extremally disconnected (ED), Open Unresolvable (OU), ED and OU, Partition space, Discrete space and the Kuratowski space.

He says the above six different Kuratowski monoids of n.e. topological spaces admit a natural partial order. It is Defined as follows:

$\mathbb{M}_1 \leq \mathbb{M}_2$ if $\exists$ a monoid homomorphism from $\mathbb{M}_2$ onto $\mathbb{M}_1$, Now he gives that there is a monoid homomorphism between $ED$ and $OU$ space. I define it as:

$f:OU \rightarrow ED\text{ and }OU $ as follows which is an homomorphism.

$f(c)=c;f(i)=i;f(ic)=f(cic)=f(ici)=f(ci)=f(ic)=ic;f(id)=id$

I have to rule out $\nexists$ any homomorphism between OU and partition space??? Can someone help me with this how to go about it as to how to rule out $\nexists$ any map between these spaces??

Comment: What is n.e.? non-equivalent?

Comment: One of my favorite professors never abbreviated anything.  There is something to be said for that.  Extremely unjustifiably, "n.e." here abbreviates "nonempty".

Comment: @mathematrucker Thanks for the correction,Its correct n.e. means nonempty here in this context.

Comment: A natural homomorphism $f$ from the OU monoid onto the ED and OU monoid sends every element to "itself" (letting $b$ denote closure and $i$ interior, in the OU monoid $bi$ and $ib$ are distinct, whereas in the ED and OU monoid they are identical).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a homomorphism between any two monoids (send everything to the identity element).  What the authors are claiming instead is that no homomorphism maps the OU monoid $onto$ the partition monoid.

$Proof.$ Using the authors' notation, let $a$ denote complement, $b$ closure and $i$ interior (we use these same symbols for both monoids, as the context will always be clear).

The OU monoid has ten distinct elements: $\tt id$, $b$, $i$, $bi$ ($=bib$), $ib$ ($=ibi$), and $a$ applied to each of these five.  The partition monoid has six distinct elements: $\tt id$, $b$ ($=ib$), $i$ ($=bi$), and $a$ applied to each of these three (operators get applied in right-to-left order in the paper; for example $ai$ represents the complement of the interior).

$Lemma.$ In the partition monoid, $\left(\{x,y\}\cap\{a,\tt id\}=\emptyset\right)\implies\left(\{y,xy\}\subset\{s,as\}\right)$ for some
$s\in\{b,i\}$.

(See below for an exhaustive proof of the lemma.)

Suppose $g$ is a monoid homomorphism from the OU monoid into the partition monoid.

We have $g(a)g(a)=g(aa)=g({\tt id})=\tt id$.  Thus $g(a)\in\{a,\tt id\}$.

If $g(a)=\tt id$, it follows that $g$ maps the OU monoid into $\{g(b),g(i),g(bi),g(ib),\tt id\}$, a set of at most five elements, hence $g$ is not surjective.

We can therefore assume $g(a)=a$.

Case 1: $g(i)\in\{a,\tt id\}$.

If $g(i)=\tt id$, then $g(b)=g(aia)=g(a)g(i)g(a)=a({\tt id})a=\tt id$.
If $g(i)=a$, then $g(b)=g(aia)=g(a)g(i)g(a)=aaa=a$.

It follows that $g$ maps the OU monoid
into $\{a,\tt id\}$ and is therefore not surjective.

Case 2: $g(b)\in\{a,\tt id\}$.

Interchanging $i$ and $b$ in the proof of Case 1
shows that $g$ again maps the OU monoid into $\{a,\tt id\}$.

Case 3: $\{g(i),g(b)\}\cap\{a,\tt id\}=\emptyset$.

Since the OU monoid satisfies $i(bi)=ib$, we have $g(i)g(bi)=g(i(bi))=g(ib)$. We also have $g(b)g(i)=g(bi)$. By the lemma, it follows that
$\{g(i),g(b),g(ib),g(bi)\}\subset\{s,as\}$ for some $s\in\{b,i\}$. Noting that $g(at)=g(a)g(t)=ag(t)$ for all $t$, this implies that $g$ maps
the OU monoid into $\{s,as,a,\tt id\}$, hence $g$ is not surjective.

Conclude there is no surjective homomorphism from the OU monoid onto the partition monoid. $\square$

Conversely it is trivial that no surjective mapping exists from the partition monoid onto the OU monoid.  The OU and partition monoids are therefore not related under the partial order.

$Proof\ of\ Lemma.$ Here is a multiplication table for the subset $\{b,i,ab,ai\}$ of the partition monoid:

$\matrix{
ib&=&b&&&&&&&&\cr
bb&=&b&&&&&&&&\cr
ii&=&i&&&&&&&&\cr
bi&=&i&&&&&&&&\cr
\cr
i(ab)&=&aba(ab)&=&ab&&&&&&\cr
b(ab)&=&a(aba)b&=&a(ib)&=&ab&&&&\cr
i(ai)&=&(aba)a(aba)&=&ababa&=&a(bi)&=&ai&&\cr
b(ai)&=&ba(aba)&=&b(ba)&=&ba&=&a(aba)&=&ai\cr
\cr
(ai)b&=&ab&&&&&&&&\cr
(ab)b&=&ab&&&&&&&&\cr
(ai)i&=&ai&&&&&&&&\cr
(ab)i&=&ai&&&&&&&&\cr
\cr
(ai)(ab)&=&b&&&&&&&&\cr
(ab)(ab)&=&b&&&&&&&&\cr
(ai)(ai)&=&i&&&&&&&&\cr
(ab)(ai)&=&i&&&&&&&&\cr}$

Comment: I went through the proof.I am almost convinced by your way of proof.Just would like to clarify these two points.(1)In the lemma i think we should have the result as $\{xy,yx\} \subseteq \{s,as\}$ because $y$ is already an operator in the partition monoid.\\(2)Also in the main proof the case 3 should be $\{g(i),g(b)\} \cap \{a,id\}=\phi$ then only it will exhaust all the possible cases for the images of the operators in the partition monoid.I may be getting it wrong..Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake in case 3 (corrected).  The lemma was correct as stated.  Let $x$ and $y$ be elements from $\{b,i,ab,ai\}$ in the partition monoid.  We have $x=pq$ and $y=rs$ for some $\{p,r\}\subset\{a,\tt id\}$ and $\{q,s\}\subset\{b,i\}$.  The lemma says that $xy=ts$ for some $t\in\{a,\tt id\}$.

Comment: In the lemma say if $x=b$ and $y=ai$ then $xx=b$,$xy=ai$,$yx=ab$,$yy=i$,then for all combinations we have got different operators which is 4 in number then how come it is equal to "ts" "for some" $t \in \{a,id\}$ .May be its a silly doubt but i am not getting the conclusion of the lemma being  used in case 3 to rule out the surjective nature of the map because may be it comes onto in some combination.If you could please elaborate.

Comment: The key result is $\{g(i),g(b),g(ib),g(bi)\}\subset\{s,as\}$ for some $s\in\{b,i\}$.
This is verified by applying the lemma repeatedly.
Under the case 3 assumption and since $g$ is a homomorphism, $\{g(i),g(bi)\}\cap\{a,{\tt id}\}=\emptyset$.
Thus by the lemma, $g(bi)$ and $g(i)g(bi)$ ($=g(ib)$) both belong to $\{s,as\}$ for some $s\in\{b,i\}$.
So do $g(b)$ and $g(i)g(b)$ ($=g(ib)$).  So do $g(i)$ and $g(b)g(i)$ ($=g(bi)$).  Hence
the same $s$ applies to $g(i),g(b),g(ib),g(bi)$.

Comment: In my first comment the specific case $x=b$, $y=ai$ is represented by $p=\tt id$, $q=b$, $r=t=a$, $s=i$.